# Issues with a method in a inventory tracker

Tags: java

This is my first post on stack exchange so i'm not really sure what you need but here's my issue:

I am creating an inventory tracker for my java class and I am running into an issue where I can't use the method addItem(Item newItem) because the class Inventory isn't static and does not have a constructor. We have a UML Diagram
[image: uml diagram]

we are supposed to work off of and it doesn't include a constructor for Inventory and says nothing about static.

I'm not really sure what else you need but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
public class InventoryTrackerInterface {

    public Inventory inv;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //test item
        Item b1 = new Item("abc",1,123,"01345");
    }
}

public class Inventory {

    private Item[] itemArray;
    private int totalItems = 0;

    public int getTotalNumberOfItems() {
        return totalItems;
    }

    public Item getItem(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= totalItems) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return itemArray[index];
        }
    }

    public void addItem(Item newItem) {
        if (newItem == null) {
            System.out.println("Item not added.");
        } else {
            itemArray[totalItems] = newItem;
            totalItems++;
        }
    }

    public void saveInventoryToFile(String fileName) {
    }

    public void loadInventoryFromFile(String fileName) {
    }
} 

public class Item {

   private String name;
   private int quantity;
   private double price;
   private String upc;

   private Item() {



   }


   public Item(String name, int qty, double price, String upc) {



   }


   public String getName() {

      return name;

   }


   public int getQuantity() {

      return quantity;

   }

   public double getPrice() {

      return price;

   }

   public String getUPC() {

      return upc;

   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show you code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly define a constructor in order to instantiate a class. In such cases, a default constructor is automatically created.
UML diagrams will usually only indicate constructors in cases where you would need one with parameters, as in the case of Item.

You can either define your inv property as static:

```
public class InventoryTrackerInterface
{
    public static Inventory inv;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         // Test items
         Item b2 = new Item("abc",1,123,"01345");
         Item c2 = new Item("dfe",2,456,"56789");

         // Inventory object
         inv = new Inventory();

         inv.addItem(b2);
         inv.addItem(c2);

     }
}
```

Or access it through an InventoryTrackerInterface instance:

```
public class InventoryTrackerInterface
{
    public Inventory inv;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         // Test items
         Item b2 = new Item("abc",1,123,"01345");
         Item c2 = new Item("dfe",2,456,"56789");

         InventoryTrackerInterface instance = new InventoryTrackerInterface();

         // Inventory object
         instance.inv = new Inventory();

         instance.inv.addItem(b2);
         instance.inv.addItem(c2);

     }
}
```

Comment: I don't think InventoryTrackerInterface litterally means interface in this case because we haven't gone over interfaces yet. Also you cannot have constructors in interfaces? By +main() he means public static void main because this diagram was created by my professor and he always refers to that as the main method.

Comment: You're right, even though I don't agree with the naming. Edited my answer, should be what you need.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:     Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field inv     at InventoryTrackerInterface.main(InventoryTrackerInterface.java:19)

Comment: Make inv static, my bad